# Validating an input via Regex C

Tags: c, regex, validation

I am writing a program that reads a filename from user. Before processing the input I want to check whether the file name is valid or not.

I wrote a function, but it returns everything as correct. I tested the regex with grep, and it worked, but it doesn't work with C. Can somebody point out what I am doing wrong.

valid file names: file.txt file123.txt file_123.txt f123.ext f-123.txt

un-valid file names: 123.txt /var/somefile.txt file$.txt...

### FUNCTION

```
int *validateString(char *argv){

    int *result = malloc(sizeof(int));

    *result = 0;

    int comp;
    regex_t validRegex;


    comp = regcomp(&validRegex,"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*.[a-z]+", REG_EXTENDED | REG_NOSUB);
/*
    if(comp){
        *result = 0;
        return result;
    }
*/
    if(!regexec(&validRegex, argv, 0, 0, 0)){
        *result = 1;
    }

    return result;

}
```

### TEST CODE

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<regex.h>





int *validateString(char *argv);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){


    if(!validateString(argv[1])){

        printf("you have entered a wrong regex!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*[.][a-z]+$"`

Comment: @AvinashRaj didn't work

Comment: Why do you return a pointer?

Comment: @user58697 cause i can't return the local variable result(?)

Comment: You can, and in fact you better do. Also keep in mind that the pointer is valid regardless of the regex match. If you want to return a pointer, at least dereference it in the `main`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user58697 pointed out, the problem was the if statement which was always being evaluated as true, cause I was evaluating the pointer(not the return value!). I dereferenced it as was suggested and it worked. The other solution was to return a value rather than a pointer in the function validateString.